# Pythonのセルが実行出来ません

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Python(アナコンダを使ってます)でプログラムを実行しようとした時、たまに(原因は分かりません)プログラムの順番を示す所が `[1]` とかではなく `[*]` となってしまい、その状態でプログラムを実行しても実行出来ず、新しいセルが追加されるか下のセルに移動して実行出来ません。

プログラムが実行出来ない理由と元のプログラムが実行出来るようにするにはどうすれば良いのかを知りたいです。初心者なので出来るだけ分かりやすくお願いしたいです。
以下プログラムが実行できない時のセル

↓ここが変化してしまいます。

```
[*]: print('k')
```

Answer (score 1):

（この回答は`Anaconda`の`Jupyter Notebook` をお使いになっているのではないかという推測で書いています）

スタックオーバーフローの本家の

- [ipython - What 'In [*]' mean in jupyter notebook - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41749586/what-in-mean-in-jupyter-notebook/48376400)
- [python - What does In [*] in IPython Notebook mean and how to turn it off? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421373/what-does-in-in-ipython-notebook-mean-and-how-to-turn-it-off)

のあたりが参考になると思います。

回答やコメントに「カーネルがビジー」や「評価中」とあります。
かんたんに言うとコンピュータが忙しいので今新しい処理を受け付けることができないことを意味しています（もしかしたら待っていたら動くときもあるかもしれませんね）。

- [How to restart the Jupyter kernel – IDEAS? What Should We Do Next?](https://support.labs.cognitiveclass.ai/knowledgebase/articles/857388-how-to-restart-the-jupyter-kernel)

にある通り `Kernel > Restart` でリスタートできるかもしれません（状態によっては無理かもしれません）。

---

- [Python - IPython notebookでIn[*]と表示されてしまい、実行できません。｜teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/107521)

にも情報がありました。

> Kernel -> Restart した後に再実行(Shift+Enter)すると、入力できるようになりました

とありますので、`Kernel > Restart`のあとでShift+Enterもあわせて試してみるとよいかと存じます。

もしくは

> run cell, select belowのボタンを押すと実行されました。

ともあるので、試してみるとよいかと思います。